# Which Lenovo laptop is featured on the new Ubuntu homepage?

Tags: 12.10

Which Lenovo laptop is featured on the new Ubuntu homepage to highlight 12.10 (Quantal Quetzal)?

http://www.ubuntu.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a prototype or photoshoped case of one of Lenovos Ultrabook (U) Series.

At least I think it is a Prototype case, cause the Model number shows U000s, but the original Modell numbers are all but 000. ATM you can buy U310 and U410 Modells officially from the lenovo site.

Comment: Damn you beat me to it :D I spotted the U000s too.

Comment: I noticed the U000, but the super key in the image seems to be replaced the Ubuntu humanity logo, which I have seen for certain laptops that comes bundled with Ubuntu, I was wondering if this was one such laptop. Anyway the question is now closed :-)

Comment: you can get those stickers for the super key with the mixed sticker sheet in the ubuntu online shop (http://shop.canonical.com/product_info.php?products_id=718)